# jQuery UI Accordion style customization

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

How do I change the tab size, font size etc. for my jQuery Accordion?

Comment: Using CSS? Or am I missing something..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to customize your jQuery UI theme with [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)

Comment: font size doesn't work, other parameters do but not font size.
also, there's no way to change the tab size.